# Magento - call to a member function getId() on a non object

Tags: magento, collections, categories

I have the following code which shows 5 products from the current category (which has cat ID:63):

```
$_helper    = $this->helper('catalog/output');
$_category  = $this->getCurrentCategory();   
$collection = $_category->getProductCollection();
Mage::getModel('catalog/layer')->prepareProductCollection($collection);
$numProducts = 5;
$collection->setPage(1, $numProducts)->load();
```

This works fine but i want to adjust this further so it only show products that are also found in another category (cat ID:71) with `$collection->addCategoryFilter(71);` but when i do this i get the error:

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function getId() on a non-object in
```

Full code is:

```
$_helper    = $this->helper('catalog/output');
$_category  = $this->getCurrentCategory();   
$collection = $_category->getProductCollection();
Mage::getModel('catalog/layer')->prepareProductCollection($collection);

// this line throws the error
$collection->addCategoryFilter(71);

$numProducts = 5;
$collection->setPage(1, $numProducts)->load();


foreach($collection as $_product){
    // output products...
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line is incorrect

```
$collection->addCategoryFilter(71);
```

I guess your trying to filter a category with id = 71. right?
If so then, you can do it this way:

```
$catToFilter = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load(71);
$collection->addCategoryFilter($catToFilter);
```

The problem was there because you were supplying id when the category filter method was expecting an object. So you get the category object with id 71 and pass it as parameter instead.

==================================================================================

**UPDATED** : to show only the products that are common in both the categories.

```
// 1st category
$cat1 = Mage::getModel ('catalog/category')->load(63);

//2nd category
$cat2 = Mage::getModel ('catalog/category')->load(71);

//loading cat2 products
$collection = $cat2->getProductCollection();

//this keeps the common products and remaining products of cat1
$collection->addCategoryFilter($cat1);

$removeList = array();
foreach ($collection as $prod)
{
  $prodCatIds = $prod->getCategoryIds();
  //if the current collection products does not lie in cat2
  if (! in_array($cat2->getId(), $prodCatIds))
  {
    //creating a list of product ids that are not common 
    array_push($removeList , $prod->getId());
  }

}

//removing the UNCOMMON products from the collection
foreach($removeList as $rl)
  $collection->addAttributeToFilter('entity_id', array('neq' => $rl)) ;

//The collection is now ready
foreach($collection->getData() as $_product){
  //$_product details or load product object
  zend_debug::dump($_product['sku']);
}
```

A little dirty way, but hope it helps.

Comment: Likewise, I'ld recommend you to use url-key or name or other attributes than id to load the category.

Comment: Thanks for this, that works for me but i've just realised that the above is now showing products in either categories 63 OR 71, where as i need it in BOTH - anyway i can do this?

Comment: okay yes. different from what you wanted initially, check updated answer.